# Post your pictures of the Beaver Moon Lunar Eclipse here!

Tags: discussion

Last year [I posted a place for Great Conjunction photos](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/31410). As tonight's eclipse will be longest partial lunar eclipse in about 500 years, I just wanted to reach out and offer a spot to compile a list of some of your best photos! Please specify your camera specifications (shutter speed, ISO, etc.) , the time taken, and the photo (obviously). Enjoy the photos!

Comment: I have some modest photos, will post them shortly. I think it's great that you post these here in meta, *thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

Taken at 4:32 AM EST (9:32 UTC) with my old 2007 Nikon D40. I've cropped the image to focus on the Moon:

- Aperture size: f/4.5
- Exposure time: 2.2 s
- ISO: 200
- Focal length: 100 mm

[image: Cropped image to focus the Moon]